# unable to save the data in api using POST method in swift

Tags: swift3

I am not able to see the changes as per required in API, when I am using the Post method to do so can I get the correct solution. Here is the Code that I have written

```
@IBAction func savebutton(_ sender: Any) {
        if let id1 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Userid"),let usertype1 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Usertype")
        {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.shreetechnosolution.com/funded/donorprofile.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "Name=\(textname.text!)&Gender=\(textGender.text!)&Email=\(textemail.text!)&MobileNo=\(textmb.text!)&Country=\(textcountry.text!)&donorid=\(id1)&usertype=\(usertype1)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }

            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSDictionary
            let msg = json.value(forKey: "message") as! NSString!

            let alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert box!", message: "\(msg!).",delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()

            }
        }

    }
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: please can anyone help

Comment: Check your backend , whether it's getting value from app or not.

Comment: No it does not update in api response

Comment: Have your backend gets the request from you?

Comment: Dear you forgot to add `task.resume()`

Comment: And also check what request type server need for processing.